# Copying HDFS directory to local node

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I'm working on a single node Hadoop 2.4 cluster.
I'm able to copy a directory and all its content from HDFS using `hadoop fs -copyToLocal myDirectory .`

However, I'm unable to successfully do the same operations via this java code :

```
public void map Object key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration(true);
    FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf);
    hdfs.copyToLocalFile(false, new Path("myDirectory"), 
                         new Path("C:/tmp"));
}
```

This code only copies a part of `myDirectory`. I also receive some error messages :

```
14/08/13 14:57:42 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1407917640600_0013_m_000001_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: Target C:/tmp/myDirectory is a directory
```

My guess is that multiple instances of the mapper are trying to copy the same file to the same node at the same time. However, I don't see why not all the content is copied.

Is that the reason of my errors, and how could I solve it ?

Comment: Your guess is right. Why do you copy files inside the `map` function?

Comment: @AlexeyShestakov the purpose is to use an external tool in the `map` operation. Since this tool is not present from scratch, I'd like to  download it from HDFS before using it. Would you know a better way of doing so ?

Comment: You can't copy your directory in the main function ? Where you set your parameters before the MR process ...

Comment: @Ko2r From my understanding, doing so will copy the directory on the namenode. I want the directory on the datanodes.

Comment: You can copy the file into HDFS (don't care where it's stored) and then in your map function just use built-in functions for retrieve it ... is it a possible solution ? Why would you like to copy the directory on each datanode ? HDFS is a distributed File System after all ...

Comment: You can use `DistributedCache` (http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html) to copy your files on all datanodes, or you could try to copy files in the `setup` of your mapper.

Comment: @AlexeyShestakov this looks like what I want, I'll try this right away.

Comment: @AlexeyShestakov It's really what the OP was searching for, create an answer ! I wasn't aware of that functionality, gonna try it later :)

Comment: @AlexeyShestakov I used `Job#addCacheArchive` (http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html#addCacheArchive%28java.net.URI%29) which is just a non-deprecated layer on `DistributedCache` and it works, so thanks :). Would you like to put your comment in an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DistributedCache` ([documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html)) to copy your files on all datanodes, or you could try to copy files in the setup of your mapper.